# How to get Spinner OnListItemSelected to work

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am currently trying to implement a Spinner within my android application.  I am having trouble with getting the OnItemSelected method, to open a new class based on what item was selected.

I have the code shown bellow, which does not seem to work, Also since adding this is, it now from the menu when I click the button to open Film and TV it opens the wrong layout, but nothing changed other than adding the bellow code.

What should happen: Activity Starts --> Click on Film and TV --> Select item from Spinner --> New class opens based on what Item was selected.

What Happens now:  Activity Starts --> Click on Film and TV --> Wrong layout opens --> Press back on phone --> Right layout opens --> Select item from Spinner --> Nothing Happens

Code:

```
String classes[] = {"SeanConnery", "BillyConnoly", "JamesMcAvoy", "KarenGillan", "KellyMacdonald", "AshleyJensen"};
    @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

    String classSpot = classes[pos];
    try{
    Class nextClass = Class.forName("com.example.famouspeople." + classSpot);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Film.this, nextClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.famouspeople"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.famouspeople.MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.famouspeople.Film"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.famouspeople.SeanConnery"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
            <activity
        android:name="com.example.famouspeople.BillyConnoly"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
            <activity
        android:name="com.example.famouspeople.JamesMcAvoy"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
            <activity
        android:name="com.example.famouspeople.KarenGillan"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
            <activity
        android:name="com.example.famouspeople.AshleyJensen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
            <activity
        android:name="com.example.famouspeople.KellyMacdonald"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: what is the exception you have got? also did u write these activities in your mainfest `"SeanConnery", "BillyConnoly", "JamesMcAvoy", "KarenGillan", "KellyMacdonald", "AshleyJensen"` ?

Comment: You might want to clarify exactly what happens. What doesn't work about, what do you expect, etc?

Comment: Post your entire stack trace. Also, that's a very odd way to make a choice from a spinner and launch a new activity. If your classes are named correctly it should still work, but you usually won't have a new class for every data item, and even if so, you'd switch on some simpler constant or enum.

Comment: show me your `mainfest` please

Comment: Ok, I will added the stack trace(Is that logcat?), also if you have a better way of opening a new class I would be open to changing the method.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan I have uploaded the manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `mainfest` from

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.famouspeople.SeanConnery"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

To

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourJavaClassName"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.example.famouspeople.SeanConnery" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Hey, I have changed that, However When I select the first item Sean Connery from the list it opens class BillyConnoly and not SeanConnery.  Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Never mind this fixed it, I just had them in the wrong position in my list/array so the pos variable returned the wrong spot.

Answer (score 2):

to create intent you can do something like this...

```
final Context context = this;
Intent intent = new Intent(context,youractivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: That's correct, but it's basically what the Thomas already has in the question (and not an answer?).

Comment: Also, FTR, I didn't really mean to upvote this, but accidentally downvoted and tried to change back to neutral, which ends up an upvote (and if I click back down, back to downvote, so stuck up or down, I'll take up).

Comment: @CharlieCollins thnx for favour...from question i got that he is messed up with the intents...